# Classic ASP MSSQL Moved to IIS8. Query Timeout expires

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

We have two servers - One **Windows 2012 server as a web server** and one **Windows 2012 server as a SQL server (Web Edition)-** using the private IP address between them. We have production sites running on this platform fine using reasonably small databases etc.

Today we moved another website over to this setup. The site was running on a **Windows 2003 server with a SQL 2008 Server (Web Edition)** with no real issues, just the server was getting old and cranky.

I'm no MSSQL DBA but can handle most simple things fine. Here's what we did.

Took a full backup of the database on the source server - it is using **Simple recovery.**

**Copied** the DB to the 2012 server and restored it, created a user and assigned permissions to the tables and SPs etc.

Set up the site - which is a classic asp site on IIS8 and used the following connection string, which we've been using on the other sites on the new server:

```
objDBConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=10.183.5.120;Network Library=DBMSSOCN"
```

The site started up fine and connected to the database, but some pages were running very slow and eventually timing out:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e31'
Query timeout expired
```

It seemed to be more on one particular table than others. It's a large database - 3GB data excluding any log. But there was no issue with this on the old server.

We switch the A record and people started hitting the site. The site gets a couple of thousand visitors a day.

Over the course of the next couple of hours, any pages using the connection were getting less responsive until nothing and timing out.

Increasing the connection query timeout helped sometimes - but it had to be set to some crazy amount of time.

It ended with me calling Rackspace and rebooting the SQL server. On reboot the site appears to be functioning OK now. But I am concerned that we don't know what caused it.

Has anyone come across this type of issue in a similar situation?

Haven't got the cash for some crazy $400 / hour Rackspace SQL DBA for sure.